# How to reverse index a Counter and convert it into a defaultdict? Python

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, counting, defaultdict

Given a Counter, e.g.:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('123112415121361273')
Counter({'1': 7, '2': 4, '3': 3, '5': 1, '4': 1, '7': 1, '6': 1})
```

How can I reverse the index and get the counts as keys and the values as lists of original string keys?

The purpose is to convert the example above into something like this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['5', '4', '7', '6'], 3: ['3'], 4: ['2'], 7: ['1']})
```

I have tried tried manually reiterating through the `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('123112415121361273')
Counter({'1': 7, '2': 4, '3': 3, '5': 1, '4': 1, '7': 1, '6': 1})
>>> x = Counter('123112415121361273')
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict
>>> y = defaultdict(list)
>>> for s, count in x.items():
...     y[count].append(s)
... 
>>> y
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['5', '4', '7', '6'], 3: ['3'], 4: ['2'], 7: ['1']})
```

**But is there any other way to do this?**

Since the input is the string `'123112415121361273'` and the output is supposed to be the dictionary indexed by counts, **is there any way to avoid the counting step when iterating through it the first time and get to the resulting defaultdict?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no more efficient way.

Counting is best done with a mapping, which is exactly what `Counter` *does*. Since you don't know the final count for any character until you fully traversed the string, you can't know up-front what bucket to file a character into until you have completed counting.

So the *in-efficient* alternative is to start with a mapping from count to characters, then move characters up to the next bucket as you find that they already have a count. Finding that they already have a count requires that you test against every bucket, so that becomes a O(NK) solution as opposed to your straightforward linear O(N) solution that the `Counter` gives you.

```
## Warning: this is not an efficient approach; use for illustration purposes only

from collections import defaultdict

s = '123112415121361273'
count_to_char = defaultdict(set)  # use a set to avoid O(N**2) performance
max_count = 0
for char in s:  # loop over N items
    for i in range(1, max_count + 1):  # loop over up to K buckets
        if char in count_to_char[i]:
            count_to_char[i].remove(char)
            count_to_char[i + 1].add(char)
            break
    else:
        i = 0
        count_to_char[1].add(char)
    max_count = max(i + 1, max_count)
# remove empty buckets again
for count in [c for c, b in count_to_char.items() if not b]:
    del count_to_char[count]
# alternative method to clear empty buckets, producing a regular dict
# count_to_char = {c: b for c, b in count_to_char.items() if b}
```

The way to avoid that scan over K buckets is to use a counter, which you already use.

Comment: I get a syntax error at `for count in [c, b for c in count_to_char.items() if not b]:`  I tried with python 3.5.2 and 2.7.12. How to make this run? Thanks!

Comment: @IvanChaer: sorry, that was a typo. I need to emphasise that that example should not actually be used.

Comment: No problem! Still, the `max_count = max(i + 1, max_count)` line seems to be unindented.

Comment: @IvanChaer: that line is correctly indented. It is part of the `for char in s:` loop.

Comment: @IvanChaer: new, now with actual testing (the point was to illustrate the idea, not to actually run it, but now I added the missing *not counted yet* edgecase).

Comment: Cool, it ran this time!

Comment: I added the timeit results to all the methods we discussed to my response.

Answer (score 1):

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import choice
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from string import printable

def str_count(input_num, defaultdict=defaultdict):

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for count, s in map(lambda x: (input_num.count(x), x), set(input_num)):
        d[count].append(s)
    return d

def counter(input_num, defaultdict=defaultdict, Counter=Counter):
    x = Counter(input_num)
    y = defaultdict(list)
    for s, count in x.items():
        y[count].append(s)
    return y

def pieters_default_dict(input_num, defaultdict=defaultdict):
    x = defaultdict(int)
    for c in input_num:
        x[c] += 1
    y = defaultdict(list)
    for s, count in x.items():
        y[count].append(s)
    return y

def pieters_buckets(input_num, defaultdict=defaultdict):
    ## Warning: this is not an efficient approach; use for illustration purposes only
    count_to_char = defaultdict(set)  # use a set to avoid O(N**2) performance
    max_count = 0
    for char in input_num:  # loop over N items
        for i in range(1, max_count + 1):  # loop over up to K buckets
            if char in count_to_char[i]:
                count_to_char[i].remove(char)
                count_to_char[i + 1].add(char)
                break
        else:
            i = 0
            count_to_char[1].add(char)
        max_count = max(i + 1, max_count)
    # remove empty buckets again
    for count in [c for c, b in count_to_char.items() if not b]:
        del count_to_char[count]
    return count_to_char

test = ''.join([choice(printable) for _ in range(1000)])
number = 100

print('str_count:                 ', timeit('f(t)', 'from __main__ import str_count as f, test as t', number=number))
print('pieters_default_dict:      ', timeit('f(t)', 'from __main__ import pieters_default_dict as f, test as t', number=number))
print('Counter:                   ', timeit('f(t)', 'from __main__ import counter as f, test as t', number=number))
print('pieters_buckets:           ', timeit('f(t)', 'from __main__ import pieters_buckets as f, test as t', number=number))
```

Timeit with Python 2.7.12 and iteritems() returned:

```
pieters_default_dict:       0.013843059539794922
str_count:                  0.016570091247558594
Counter:                    0.030740022659301758
pieters_buckets:            0.1262810230255127
```

And on Python 3.5.2 and items():

```
Counter:                    0.00771436400100356
pieters_default_dict:       0.013124741999490652
str_count:                  0.017287666001720936
pieters_buckets:            0.11816959099996893
```

*UPDATE*

- Eliminated an unnecessary loop from the str_count() function, thanks to Martijn Pieters.
- This script was tested on Python 2.7.12

*UPDATE 2*

- Removed the import from the functions, following up the comments.
- Fixed the code copied from the question, as two counters were being created.

*UPDATE 3*

- Added the timeit results to the two other versions of the script elaborated by Pieters.
- Added the timeit results on Python 3.5.2
- The pieters_buckets() method was created for illustration purposes only, so it's timed here just for curiosity.

*UPDATE 4*

- Fixed the code to use a random string and a larger number of repetitions.

Comment: I can't reproduce these timings, what Python version is this on? Your approach uses a O(KN) algorithm so won't scale to large inputs (for every unique value you run a full scan to count), while the original is a O(N) approach. Also, why the extra imports in the functions and why a dict with only one key and value in the loop?

Comment: Test run on ideone.com (using Python 3.4): http://ideone.com/bGKI8z I cleaned up your approach and avoided importing multiple times, creating counters multiple times, avoided making a dict where a tuple would do and avoided globals.

Comment: On Python 2 the `Counter` class is pure python and thus has a higher constant cost, so counting there is slower. This only means you need a larger K and N before it is clear that algorithmically, using `str.count()` is going to lose.

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters! Thanks for your input. Yes, I'm running 2.7. I added the imports inside the functions because I was interested in also timing the imports. Not sure this is good practice or even correct, tho. I like the way you eliminated one of the loops. I'm gonna update my answer as such.

Comment: The imports do not make a difference here; both classes come from the same module. An import loads the module only the *first* time, after that it's simply retrieved from `sys.modules`; all that remains is setting a global or local name to reference an attribute on the module object. That said, rebinding `Counter` twice is just busy-work that doesn't need to be executed.

Comment: You are still using `Counter()` twice. That's a rather unfair disadvantage. Yes, for the small string input you have here, the pure-Python loop in the Counter class on Python 2 is going to hurt as the constant cost per iteration is higher. That still doesn't make using `str.count()` a better idea, algorithmically speaking, as that has to do a full scan of the input string. Scale that input string up scanning that string K times is going to be beaten by the `Counter` doing it just once.

Comment: The code I used in Python 3 runs cleanly in Python 2 too, although you really want to use `dict.iteritems()` and avoid creating a list. Timings for Counter don't look so good there either because of the high constant cost of running the loop: http://ideone.com/TqHMR3, so even with N=10K and K~=100 that cost is hefty. As long as you document that difference and the reasons, using `str.count()` can be a sane choice. But *do document this* and be aware of why there is a difference. The moment you move to Python 3 the reasoning no longer applies.

Comment: Last, but not least, replacing the `Counter` with `x = defaultdict(int)` and `for c in input_num: x[c] += 1` makes the times almost equal again: http://ideone.com/illuiZ, so Python 2's `Counter` makes you pay a price by abstracting a little too much somewhere.

Comment: Nice idea, to replace the Count with another use of defaultdict. :)

Comment: You redefined `counter()` (one without and one with locals bound to the globals), so only the latter will be used. Do test this with *large* inputs, like I did in my ideone.com tests; the algorithms will really differ when pushing N and K up to high numbers.

Comment: Done! :) I think it's ok this time.

Comment: You are not actually *using* the `test` value, all your tests still use the `'123112415121361273'` string literal. The `pieters_buckets()` function doesn't use `defaultdict` as a local either.

Comment: Also, on Python 2, the use of `dict.items()` vs. `dict.iteritems()` is going to matter, so you may want to run there with that one change.

Comment: Wow, much different results indeed!